# Toolbar content not appearing despite fragment content appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I'm trying to show the necessary content within my toolbar (i.e. the title and back button) but for some reason is doesn't appear but yet the main content within my fragment does. What can be done to resolve this issue?

**MapActivity.java**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);

        SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.map));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            final Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**FragmentMap.java**

```
public class FragmentMap extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public FragmentMap() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#212121"));

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.map) + "</font>"));
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


        return v;
    }
}
```

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentmap" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/actionBar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="16dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Complete Code

### MapActivity

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MapActivityFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                super. onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### activity_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentmap" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/actionBar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="16dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### styles.xml

```
<style name="AppThemeNew" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>
```

### MapActivityFragment.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MapActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MapActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + "Hello Toolbar" + "</font>"));
        return rootView;

    }
}
```

### fragment_map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blackColor"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#212121"));

    //---- changes ---
    ((MapActivity) getActivity()).setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.map) + "</font>"));
    ((MapActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((MapActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


    return v;
}
```

Comment: That's now available within my question.